# Array as index in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, indexing

I am trying to use an array (`mask`) which has binary values to modify another array (`data`), in order to keep only the values where `mask` is equal to 1

This is my MATLAB example code:

```
mask = [0 0 0 1 1 0 0];

data = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];

data(mask == 0) = []
```

My result is then:

```
data = [4 5]
```

What is the equivalent operation to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: Don't understand the downvote.  People switching over between Python and MATLAB ask this question all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [Boolean index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) in `numpy` which do exactly what you describe.

For example, your code in `numpy` flavor looks like:

```
In [38]: import numpy as np
In [39]: mask = np.array([False, False, False, True, True, False, False])
In [40]: data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
In [41]: data[mask]

Out[41]: array([4, 5])
```

In general, if you are looking to create a MATLAB like environment in Python, you should try to use `numpy`, `pandas`, `ipython` and `matplotlib` together. These are all excellent libraries that replicate the MATLAB ecosystem and in some cases give you even more powerful tools.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sure. I will update my answer shortly. No more down votes please :)

Comment: Ok this is the best solution so far! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want this purely in Python, you could use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) to filter out those entries in your `data` list that contain a `1` in the corresponding entries of `mask`.  Make a list of tuples that combine the `data` and `mask` together, use `filter` and use the first element of each tuple to determine which elements in this list of tuples to keep, then simply extract the `data` part when you're done using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).  Something like:

```
In [1]: mask = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0]

In [2]: data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

In [3]: L = [(x,y) for (x,y) in zip(mask,data)]

In [4]: F = filter(lambda z: z[0], L)

In [5]: data = map(lambda z: z[1], F)

In [5]: data
Out[5]: [4, 5]
```

However, if you want to best do the logical indexing efficiently, I would use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) to do that for you.  Create a `numpy` array of your `mask` and `data`, then use logical indexing like in MATLAB to get what you want:

```
In [6]: import numpy as np

In [7]: L = np.array(data)

In [8]: M = np.array(mask, dtype='bool')

In [9]: data = list(L[M])

In [10]: data
Out[10]: [4, 5]
```

If you're coming from MATLAB and are switching over to Python, `numpy` is the way to go.  The syntax used to slice through the arrays and the built-in functions used on `numpy` arrays is very akin to how you'd do the same operations in MATLAB.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Even for a general array (meaning non-boolean), this can be achieved by directly using the mask as the index.

```
In [16]: a
Out[16]: array([1, 2])

In [17]: b
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [18]: b[a]
Out[18]: 
array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [19]: b[:, a]
Out[19]: 
array([[ 2,  3],
       [ 7,  8],
       [12, 13]])
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I got. However, if you want cleaner code then you could wait for some bigwigs to answer:

```
mask = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for index, one in enumerate(mask):
    if one == 1:
        print data[index],
print
```

**Output :** `4,5`

Comment: Ok in this way I can access the right elements, but how to delete these elements from data?

Comment: You can write these values into a new list.